# Get owner of deposit (JPA repository)

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have problem, how to get Person object (code below) where deposits set contain Deposit object. I have to create function to my repository, that return single Person class object.

My Person class:

```
public class Person {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    protected int id;
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected String pesel;
    @OneToMany
    protected Set<Deposit> deposits;
}
```

And my Deposit class:

```
public class Deposit {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    protected long id;
    protected String depositNumber;
    @OneToMany
    protected Set<Credit> credits;
    @OneToMany
    protected Set<Transfer> transfers;
}
```

Comment: You want to get a person object based on what? By person id? by Deposit id?

Comment: Based on deposit id or Deposit object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Person object based on deposit object, you will have to map Person <-> Deposit relationship in Deposit object too. Assuming Person <-> Deposit is one-to-many, in tables, you will have FK of person id in Deposit table. That's what is missing in your Deposit class. Change the Deposit class as shown below

```
public class Deposit {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    protected long id;
    protected String depositNumber;
    @OneToMany
    protected Set<Credit> credits;
    @OneToMany
    protected Set<Transfer> transfers;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
}
```

Get deposit object by id using `DepositRepository` and then do `deposit.getPerson()`